# Canvas draw image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to draw a picture in a canvas, but its not working and I have no idea why. Here is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('profile-pic');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 150, 150);
};
imageObj.src = '/images/alt-profile.png';
```

```html
<canvas id='profile-pic' height="150" width="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: Try `context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);`  I think you're drawing **at** 150, 150 which is beyond the bounds of the canvas.

Comment: that worked thankyou!

Answer (score 3):

Look at the API of [`drawIamge`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).  The `dx` and `dy` are the coordinates of where you want to draw the image.

You provided `150, 150`.  Your canvas' `width` and `height` are both **150**.

That means, you are trying to draw an image at the location `150, 150` meaning you are drawing right at the outside corner of the canvas.

Change the value of the arguments you are providing to `drawIamge` to something within the bounds of the canvas, i.e. greater than the image dimensions, but less than the canvas dimensions.